# Delete Huge file in linux

Tags: files, rm

I would like to delete a large file in my server. It's very large nearly more than TB's. What is the best way to delete that huge file ???

Comment: Do you have any problem with just doing `rm` that file?

Comment: I taught it will fail. because it's in TB's

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have sufficient permissions to delete the file, simply deleting with the rm command should be sufficient:

```
rm <filename>
```

Note that the size of the file is irrelevant. When you delete a file, it typically isn't wiped in its entirety - instead the inode that points to the disk space is simply marked as unused.  The disk space is then reused as and when necessary when files are added or expanded.

Comment: It's important to note that the disk space used by the file will only be reused when all links to the file have been closed - and a process that has the file open is a link to the file.  Deleting the file will not release the disk space if a process has it open.